# CMake: How to build multiple projects exported for find_package() via add_subdirectory()

Tags: cmake

I have a Library Project that is exported so consumers can use it like so:

```
find_package(myLibrary)
target_link_libraries(theirLibrary PUBLIC myNamespace::myLibrary)
```

MyLibrary is the main product but it lives alongside two other projects in our repository, and the layout looks like this:

```
MyRepository/
  MyLibrary/
    CMakeLists.txt
    include/ //public headers
    MyLibrary/ //sources and private headers
  MyDependentLibrary/ //another library project
    CMakeLists.txt
    etc..
  MyExample //executable project
    CMakeLists.txt
    etc..
```

The dependencies for each project are like so:

```
MyLibrary: None
MyDependentLibrary: MyLibrary
MyExample: MyLibrary, MyDependentLibrary
```

MyLibrary and MyDependentLibrary are both set up with install and build directory exports to be compatible with the find_package() command. So to build everthing you:

1. configure/build MyLibrary
2. configure MyDependantLibrary setting `MyLibrary_DIR` when prompted, then build it
3. configure MyExample setting `MyLibrary_DIR` and `MyDependentLibrary_DIR` when prompted, then build it

This workflow is great, most of the time we only want to package MyLibrary without the other projects when we send to customers, but occasionally we want to give them the source for all 3 projects so they have more examples to look at.

For that reason I would love to add a top level `CMakeLists.txt` file that would I imagine look something like this:

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
    
   project(MyCombinedProject VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
    
   add_subdirectory(MyLibrary)
   add_subdirectory(MyDependentLibrary)
   add_subdirectory(MyExample)
```

However this doesn't work. When configuring the "combined" project, MyDependentLibrary is unable to find `MyLibrary_DIR`, which makes sense, as MyLibrary hasn't been built yet.

Is there a way to add an export to each of the libraries so they can be found when added in this manner in addition to the find_package()? I really don't want to move any CMake code required to build MyLibrary into the top level `CMakeLists.txt`, as 90% of the time it will be delivered on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You may ship the sources of your library (MyLibrary) with a pseudo config file, which just provides `myNamespace::myLibrary` target as alias for `myLibrary`.

**MyLibrary/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Assuming you create a library
add_library(mylibrary ...)
# Install and export it
install(TARGETS mylibrary EXPORT mylibraryTargets ...)
# and install the file which describes this installation
install(EXPORT mylibraryTargets NAMESPACE myNamespace ...)
# Then you install config file for your library:
install(FILES myLibrary.cmake ...)

# Then just set `MyLibrary_DIR` variable to point into in-source version of config file.
set(MyLibrary_DIR CACHE INTERNAL "A directory with the in-source config file"
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake
)
```

And write that in-source config file as follows:

**MyLibrary/cmake/MyLibraryConfig.cmake**:

```
add_library(myNamespace::mylibrary ALIAS mylibrary)
```

That way, `find_package(MyLibrary)` will work if it is issued after configuring sources of your library (`add_subdirectory(MyLibrary)`).